# How to change parse server mount url to main root url "/"

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

Here is my index.js file, i have changed below line so i can mount the parse server in root url for example `parse.example.com:1337` instead of `parse.example.com:1337/parse`  but Im not sure if it is correct way and i have very little experience with nodejs and javascript

`"var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';" to " var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/';"`

## index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://parse:secretpass@127.0.0.1:27017/parsedb',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
   
var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

Comment: I would recommend you not to do it, this is really a networking convention that many people uses... this has to be changed in http server like Nginx or Apache and if you dont have any experience with it, just Never touch a running server! or just follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use NGINX as a reverse proxy.

Install the nginx package:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nginx
```

Open /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Replace it with the following:

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - serve HTML from /usr/share/nginx/html, proxy requests to /parse/
# through to Parse Server
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name your_domain_name;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        # Use certificate and key
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/your_domain_name/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/your_domain_name/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        # Pass requests for /parse/ to Parse Server instance at localhost:1337
        location /parse/ {
                rewrite ^/parse(/.*)$ $1 break;# this is the line that will redirect to root url
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Save, exit and restart

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Update:

1. Parse Server needs an ssl certificate to work by default, you can disable it but it is very strongly recommended to only use it via HTTPS.
2. I am using Lets Encrypt certificates, if you need help creating them I can show you a tutorial I wrote, or you can use your own certificates.

Comment: your copy & paste config doesnt explain Letsencrypt SSL certificates... or even why you force him to switch to https

Comment: @MazelTov first, parse only works via https by default, you can force it to use http but its a really big security risk because your access tokens will be visible. Second, I am personally using lets encrypt certificates, he can use which ever one he wants.

Comment: I would say that parse-server doesnt have much in common with http or https cause it is web server thing, Second your config is wrong, he was asking to change /parse to / but you are showing him /parse/ instead

Comment: and I believe even at parse.com they once said that AppID and ClientID are supposed to be public... I found it [https://parse.com/questions/are-the-application-id-and-client-key-safe-to-put-in-the-android-client](https://parse.com/questions/are-the-application-id-and-client-key-safe-to-put-in-the-android-client)

Comment: @MazelTov really, sacrificing a layer of security based on a comment?
I agree it is a best practice to have all the ACL rules in order, that is very much understood using Parse, but why in the world will you maker your access keys public? 
As an experiment make your public in a comment, and let's see what we can do with them ;)

Comment: i prefer https over http, dont get me wrong... you were just saying that AppID is meant to be a secret and it is not true because it is not designed this way.... puting those keys here on the internet is very stupid, but decompiling Android application is very easy and you can find those keys there too...